# Stopping the Google Now swipe gesture being recognised

Tags: android, swipe, android-4.2-jelly-bean, google-now

At work I am currently facing a problem where the new gesture in Jelly Bean that opens Google Now is causing a problem related to our design.

The app is due very shortly and so redesigning the layout is not possible. Basically the problem is that we are using a Sliding Drawer located at the bottom of the screen, JellyBean users will find that they often accidentally launch the Google Now app when swiping for the sliding drawer at the bottom of the screen.

Is it possible to disable the Google Now Launch gesture on a per activity basis? Or even at the application level for now until we get the chance to redesign the GUI?

Comment: Yeah this new feature is horrible, they should have given us a way to disable it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace Google Now gesture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233330/replace-google-now-gesture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this possible, but wouldn't it be easier to move the sliding drawer from the bottom of the screen and instead place at the top and slide down.

Comment: Probably, as long as you don't run into the same problem with the notifications panel. I've done that several times in apps that have a swipe-down gesture.

Comment: That is a good point as well, forgot about the notification panel

Comment: In the end a UI re-design was required, it was just unfortunate timing for us. It does not appear to be possible to disable the response to the gesture at any level.

Comment: I found this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.AdrianCampos.googlenowswipedisabler . It works now but I havent found the way to do it. Google may prevent that in the future too