# Replace Google Now gesture

Tags: android, google-now

If you want to start Google Now on Nexus devices, you swipe-up with a simple gesture from the navbar. I want go replace this feature with my own app. if you swipe the, app-picker comes and asks you which app do you want to start: my app or Google Now. How can I implement this?

I have found [an example](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simon.LaunchNow) which runs without root.

Comment: Can you check if my changes matched what you meant?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add the following `<intent-filter>` to the Activity you want launched from the gesture:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

You will now see an option for your app when you make the swipe now, and will have to select it as the default handler by selecting Always, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to get your own icon inside the circle?

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.android.systemui.action_assist_icon"
            android:resource="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

Comment: does not work for me, it starts google assistant on my phone and did not ask to choose from.

Answer (score 8):

It's just a matter of setting the [correct intent filter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ASSIST):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I know some intents don't fire unless you have both ACTION and CATEGORY. Maybe a category default for it?

Comment: that dont help me. Set this on AndroidManifest or where?

Comment: hi, I edited to add an example. Please remember that it's purely guess-work of mine considering my experience. But it might be completely wrong.