# Android change app logo on drag from navbar like google now

Tags: android

Hi i want to change my application logo on drag from navigation bar like google now.
This is my application manifest:

```
    <application
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

[image: Exmaple]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace Google Now gesture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233330/replace-google-now-gesture)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your AndroidManifest, add this `intent-filter` and `meta-data` to the `Activity` you would like to launch when you swipe up.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.android.systemui.action_assist_icon"
            android:resource="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />
```

The first time you swipe up, the generic search icon will be shown. After you choose to "always" use your app as the default assist action, the icon your specify in your AndroidManifest will appear. Also, bear in mind this isn't official. Typically you can't modify the SystemUI, but this is a special case.

[image: Example]

Comment: I already have it in my activity manifest it doesn't change the app icon.

Comment: Adding it to your manifest doesn't change it. You need to swipe all the way up so you can make your app the default action.

Comment: Found a soulotion and used it alongside with yours and it worked thank s

Comment: I have another question:Can I put another apps in the semi-circle?

Comment: @Resonpin what is your solution? Can you share it please?