# How to block "Google Search" appearing when long pressed HOME key?

Tags: android, android-homebutton, long-press

I'm developing a Home screen application for android. But when the HOME key is long pressed "Google Now" search always appears - I want to avoid that. I found that the android framework does not give a HOME key press event out to application level.

Since this is a home screen app I can detect HOME key short press, but not the long press.
So how can I block/disable this system search activity coming up when HOME key is long pressed?

Comment: i hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17549478/how-to-disable-home-and-other-system-buttons-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace Google Now gesture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233330/replace-google-now-gesture)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://www.juliencavandoli.com/how-to-disable-recent-apps-dialog-on-long-press-home-button/) old article (2012/09, Android 4.1.1) can help you :

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    Log.d("Focus debug", "Focus changed !");

    if(!hasFocus) {
        Log.d("Focus debug", "Lost focus !");

        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
    }
}
```